# Ember Data: What are some good online learning material for Ember Data?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am new in `Ember` and `Ember Data`. Although I have learned `Ember` but I will find myself uncomfortable when I have to work with `model adapter serializer and store` thing of `ember`. Could anyone please suggest some good online learning resource for ember? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ember Data in the Wild by David Tang  https://leanpub.com/emberdatainthewild

and Emberscreencasts https://www.emberscreencasts.com/search?q=ember+data

also check next series http://emberwatch.com/screencasts.html

Comment: is there is any site where i could find Ember Data in the Wild by David Tang for free

Comment: not sure - you can get source at github, but book - not sure